# If the string contain 0 or negative value change text

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the text according to the number, but the result always gives me fault.

http://jsfiddle.net/2sboq50j/

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

var matches = $(".content").text().match(/\d/);

  if (matches){
     $(".result").text('There is a Number!');    
  } else if (matches === 0 || matches <= 0) {
     $(".result").text('Number cannot be negative or 0.');    
  } else {
     $(".result").text('There is no Number!');
  }

});
```

If there is 0 or less than 0 in the paragraph, it should return
Number cannot be negative or 0.

If the value is more than 0
There is a Number!

If no number
There is no Number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the order of your `if` statement

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var matches = parseInt($(".content").text().match(/-?\d+/g));
  if (matches === 0 || matches <= 0) {
    $(".result").text('Number cannot be negative or 0.');
  } else if (matches) {
    $(".result").text('There is a Number!');
  } else {
    $(".result").text('There is no Number!');
  }

});
```

In your original code, 0 is considered a match so the first statement is true and the rest is disregarded.

As for negative numbers, you need to changer your regex to allow hyphens "-" since they're part of the negative number.

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58xv92hf/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much, but if there is a negative value, it should return "Number cannot be negative or 0." but now is "There is a Number!"

Comment: @user9030616 The problem is with your regex . It's only accepting digits (so no negatives. I updated the answer.

Comment: @VVV, the else case doesn't seem to work in your jsfiddle example.

Answer (score -2):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

  var matches = $(".content").text().match(/\d/);
  alert("matches -->" + matches);

  if (matches > 0){
     $(".result").text('There is a Number!');    
  } else if (matches == 0 || matches <= 0) {
     $(".result").text('Number cannot be negative or 0.');    
  } else {
     $(".result").text('There is no Number!');
  }

});
```

Can you try this.

Comment: Thank you very much, but negative value should return "Number cannot be negative or 0."

Comment: ^-\d+$ This is the regex for negative numbers.

Comment: ^-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+$ is the regex for both positive and negative numbers